# How do I remove strings from the path of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

The way of what I have done inn this code, is whatever number of images you want, all you need is to have them with path as css class.

Sub.html:

```
<div>

<img src ="../images/aa.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="../images/bb.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="../images/cc.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="../images/dd.png" class="path"/>
<img src ="../images/ee.png" class="path"/>

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#main').load( "../sub.html",function(data){
  var newPath = 'css/images/';
  $.each($('.path'), function(index){
  var originalSource = $(this).attr('src');

  // Replacing the source
  var newSource = newPath + originalSource.substr(originalSource.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // Setting the new value of src
  $(this).attr('src', newSource);
});
});
```

Everything is working fine, path is getting added to the images.

URL: `localhost:8080/abc/def/ghi/jkl/css/images/aa.png.`

But required url is `localhost:8080/abc/def/css/images/aa.png.`

How do I remove `ghi` and `jkl` from url..

And `jkl` values keep changes where as `ghi` is static value it will be same everytime.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7zs7N/)

Comment: `newSource.replace(/(\/ghi|\/jkl)/g, '');`

Comment: @adeneo: Forgot to mention, jkl values are dynamic they will keep changing everytime

Comment: @adeneo: ITs not working. Tried code: var rnewSource = newSource.replace(/(\/ghi|\/jkl)/g, '');

Comment: Are the images being created dinamically? Aren't they resources?

Comment: use  either ../../../images/ee.png or images/ee.png. can you please describe Sub.html in which directory??

Comment: Well, you have to make up your mind, if you want to remove a path in the URL based on the location, i.e. counting `/` etc. you ask for that, not how to replace strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression like this:

```
var newSource = replace(/\/ghi\/[^\/]*/, '');
```

The `[^\/]` part matches everything but a `/`.
This is needed to get the variable part of the url after `/ghi` to the next `/`.

So your code would become:

```
$('#main').load( "../sub.html",function(data){
  $.each($('.path'), function(index){
    var originalSource = $(this).attr('src');

    // Replacing the source
    var newSource = originalSource.replace(/\/ghi\/[^\/]*/, '');

    // Setting the new value of src
    $(this).attr('src', newSource);
  });
});
```

**Edit**

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLWHr/). I used a simplified version of your code and everything works as expected. If you inspect the images you can see that the src attribute is replaced as it should be.

Comment: I tried but the url is still same not removing values... For example if we have "ghi-typ", does this work?

Comment: Yeah that works. Does all of your elements have the "path" class? I just tested the code using a fiddle and everything works as expected.

Comment: Did you succeed using this solution?